# Polynomials that arises from sums of first $n$ $k$-th powers

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

Define

$$\displaystyle P_k(n) = \sum_{m = 1}^n m^k,$$

which is a polynomial in $n$. Indeed, we have the following list which should be familiar to most mathematicians:

$$\displaystyle P_1(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, P_2(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}, P_3(n) = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \right)^2,$$

etc.

Curiously, we see that $P_3(n)$ is the square of a polynomial, namely $P_3(n) = P_1(n)^2$. It can be proved, using a cheeky argument that involves Catalan's conjecture (now a theorem), that this is the only time $P_k(n)$ is a perfect power: suppose otherwise, and that there exists $s \geq 2$ and $k \geq 4$ such that $P_k(n) = Q(n)^s$ for some polynomial $Q$ such that $Q(m) \in \mathbb{Z}$ whenever $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then in particular we have $P_k(2) = Q(2)^s$, so that

$$\displaystyle 1 + 2^k = Q(2)^s,$$

and since $k \geq 4$ this violates Catalan's conjecture that the only solution to $x^n - y^m = 1$ is $(x,y) = (3,2)$ and $(n,m) = (2,3)$. Since Catalan's conjecture was only proved in 2002 by  Mihăilescu, this seems like overkill. Is there a simpler proof of this fact?

Also, regarding the polynomials $P_k(n)$, it seems that for small $k$ at least that they are all reducible. One sees that $P_k(0) = 0$ for all $k$ and, so $P_k(x)$ is divisible by $x$ as a polynomial. Moreover, considering the congruence $P_k(n) \pmod{n+1}$ reveals that the left hand side is always zero, hence $x+1 | P_k(x)$ as well. Put $Q_k(x) = \dfrac{P_k(x)}{x(x+1)}$ and

$$\displaystyle S(X) = |\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k \leq X, Q_k \text{ is reducible over } \mathbb{Q}\}|.$$

Does the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{S(X)}{X}$ exist, and is it positive?

Another related question is how often the polynomials $P_k$ are square-free, that is, indivisible by the square of any polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, say. Put

$$\displaystyle T(X) = |\{k \in \mathbb{N} : k \leq X, P_k \text{ is square-free as a polynomial}\}.$$

Does $\displaystyle \lim_{X \rightarrow \infty} \frac{T(X)}{X}$ exist, and is it positive?

Comment: Maybe including the keyword "Bernoulli numbers" somewhere would be good.

Comment: You can show that $P_k(x)$ is always divisible by $x(x+1)$, so in that sense they will always be reducible. Perhaps it is more interesting to look at $P_k(x)/(x^2+x)$?

Comment: Also, solving the diophantine equation $1+2^k=r^s$ is very easy without appealing to Mihăilescu's theorem. Just note that $2^k=(r-1)(r^{s-1}+\cdots+1)$ therefore $r=2^{t}+1$ for some $t<k$. Next divide both sides by $2^t$ and take mod $2$ to conclude that $s$ must be even. This tells you that $r+1$ also divides $2^k$, but the only way $r\pm1$ are both powers of $2$ is if $r=3$ and you get the solution $1+8=9$.

Comment: These are [Faulhaber polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials) and the Wikipedia page has some good information.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi thanks for your observation! I will update the question to ask for the reducibility of $P_k(x)/(x(x+1))$ instead.

Comment: According to wikipedia (@John Machaek's link), $P_k(x)$ is always divisible by $x^2(x+1)^2$ for odd $k\ge 3$. Moreover, from the first polynomials, it is tempting to conjecture that for even $k$ the polynomial is divisible by $(2x+1)$, which would mean that your polynomials are always reducible for $k\ge 3$